# Use of the preposition "в" unrelated to time/location/direction

Tags: грамматика, падежи, предлоги

I'm definitely a beginner so apologies in advance for what may be silly questions.

This is about this sentence, particularly around the use of `в`:

> Мне смысла в этой жизни и без Кузинатры хватает

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2#Russian), `в` is used with locations, directions, and time.  But here it's used with this life which doesn't seem to fit into any of those 3.

Can you clarify what `в` means here and in what cases are `этой` and `жизни`.  The spelling alone is not sufficient as they both match many.

Also, what is the subject in this sentence (or of the propositional phrase)?  In easier examples, like `Он идёт в теа́тр`, it's straightforward to see the subject (in nominative case) is `Он`, but here there is `Мне` which is either accusative or prepositional case, so I'm confused to say to least.

This is from a [cartoon with transcript](http://www.russianforfree.com/video-smeshariki-a977b78.php).

Below is the quoted dialog:

```
Ка́рыч:  Тогда́ тебе́ нужна́ Кузина́тра ("Кузина́тра" is only a name).
Бара́ш:  Кака́я ещё Кузина́тра?
Ка́рыч:  Кузина́тра, даю́щая смысл.
Бара́ш:  Даааа! Она́ мне нужна́! Но где её иска́ть?
Ка́рыч:  Э́то о́чень далеко́. 
Бара́ш:  За смы́слом хоть на край све́та (6). Веди́ меня́!
Ка́рыч:  Нет, мне в таку́ю даль пере́ться (7) не́ за чем. Мне смы́сла в э́той 
жи́зни и без Кузина́тры хвата́ет.
```

Thanks!

Comment: texts as a learning vehicle make sense when they're preceded by grammar of which they're an example, on the referenced website i didn't notice any grammar attached to these transcripts and the texts themselves grammatically are not plain enough for a beginner, because they weren't designed as such

Comment: this is an impersonal sentence, with no subject, you're welcome to explore answers dealing with this topic under the tag **[impersonal](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/impersonal)**, i don't think this is a beginner level and will dare to opine that you may have approached the learning not from the most efficient end... the translation would be *`to me there's enough sense in this life even without Kuzinatra`* and `в этой жизни` here has the same meaning as `in this life` in the translation

Comment: Just for completeness: “Кузинатра” is a (now rather obscure) joke coming from mistranslated “What’s green and red and goes round and round and round?” <…> “A frog in a Cuisinart” (_Trumps of Doom_ by Roger Zelazny).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
what is the subject in this sentence (?)
```

In Russian, there's a type of sentence with **no subject** (*impersonal sentence*) and your example belongs to it. In English translation, such sentences *take a subject* like '**there**' or '**it**'.

To understand how it works *literally*, it might be useful to slightly change the word order in your Russian sentence,  just by moving the verb **хватает** from the very end (where that verb sounds *emphasized*) to a neutral position, just after the pronoun мне. It makes possible to match elementary Russian and English phrases:

> (1) Мне хватает смысла (2) в этой жизни (3) и без Кузинатры.
>
> (1) There is enough sense for me (2) in this life (3) without
>   Cuisinatra as well.

As you can see, the English version has the subject '**there**', *without* a counterpart in the Russian sentence, while other words can be matched almost literally:

> мне хватает = [it, there] is enough... for me;
>
> смысла (genitive case) = sense;
>
> в этой жизни = in this life;
>
> без Кузинатры = without Cuisinatra;
>
> **и** (in this context) = as well.

```
what в means here (?)
```

As you can see from the comparison of parts (2), **в** means **in** here  (*inside, within* - possible in some other context).

```
in what cases are этой and жизни (?)
```

The noun **жизнь** and the pronoun **эта** are in the **prepositional** case.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example 'в' is 'in'. That's how you specify your context or, if you wish, scope. So there are two possibilities there: "мне смысла жизни мало" or "мне смысла **в** жизни мало". Both are very similar, though the second one **could** but not necessarily has to be understood such that it references to the personal life of the author, not the Life as a phenom.

But as a beginner, please remember: "в" mostly always means "in". So you might say "**в** такой ситуации" - "in such a situation" or "в возрасте" which would mean that someone is not so young. Russians tend to use "в" quite a lot and not all of the usages can be literally translated with help of "in", but **essentially** the meaning holds: to be inside of something.